# Slanty brackets

Tags: support

When using phonemic script, it customary to put the IPA inside slanting brackets, like this: /slɑ:nti brækɪts/

Unfortunately, these often seem to break across lines on SE posts, so we get the following kind of problem occasionally:

> blah blah blah blah blah /
>
> slɑ:nti brækɪts/

It looks particularly bad if there's only one phoneme in between the brackets:

> blah blah blah blah blah /
>
> i/

Is there any way to stop this happening?

Comment: This depends on many factors, especially the details of the software where you’re typing these things on one end, and the software where it’s being rendered on the other. I don’t think there’s a general solution. Unicode might offer some [zero-width non-breaking spaces or word joiners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393767) or something, but given the current state of non-vanilla Unicode support in most software, that will raise a lot more issues than it might solve, IMO.

Comment: @Jane Are all of those factors an issue when talking specifically about posts on EL&U.SE? (That's a genuine question; I'm the rare SE participant with near-zero coding experience.)

Comment: @1006a I don’t know. I haven’t tried it. BTW this is Dan Bron. You know me. I created an alter ego with a female name because I wanted a more objective view of whether SE is exclusionary to women (the experiment was suggested by a high rep user on Meta.se). But I posted from it by mistake here.

Comment: Thanks, @DanBron. I'm frequently a bit at sea with some of the coding stuff that is assumed to be "general knowledge" around here (e.g., there's a whole SE dedicated to creating bits of code that help improve the SE experience in various interesting and attractive ways...but nowhere that I can find are there any basic instructions for what to *do* with those bits of code). Also, I'm interested to know what happens with your experiment, if you feel comfortable sharing down the line.

Comment: @danbron How about Choosing a different name? Calling yourself Jane's a bit like coming on here and calling yourself Michael or Norman or sommat ...

Comment: @Araucaria What’s wrong with Michael or Norman or Jane? Happy to pick another name, and I’m open to suggestions, given my cover is now blown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SE Markdown appears to filter out `<nobr>` tags, although browser support for this element seems to have been [removed anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr).

The Unicode solution appears to be the "[word joiner](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch23.pdf)" character, inserted after the opening slash and before the closing slash.

> ***Word Joiner.*** U+2060 `word joiner` behaves like U+00A0 `no-break space` in that it indicates the absence of line breaks; however, the 
>   *word joiner* has no width. The function of the character is to indicate that line breaks are not allowed between the adjoining characters, except next to hard line breaks. For example, the *word joiner* can be inserted after the fourth character in the text “base+delta” to indicate that there should be no line break between the “e” and the “+”. The *word joiner* can be used to prevent line breaking with other characters that do not have nonbreaking variants, such as U+2009 `thin space` or U+2015 `horizontal bar`, by bracketing the character.

The character does appear to be supported by the font in use at EL&U, though I cannot speak for others used elsewhere on SE: /⁠A⁠B⁠C⁠D⁠E⁠F⁠G⁠H⁠I⁠K⁠L⁠M⁠N⁠O⁠P⁠Q⁠R⁠S⁠T⁠V⁠X⁠Y⁠Z⁠&⁠⁊⁠Ƿ⁠Þ⁠Ð⁠Æ⁠a⁠b⁠c⁠d⁠e⁠f⁠g⁠h⁠i⁠k⁠l⁠m⁠n⁠o⁠p⁠q⁠r⁠s⁠t⁠x⁠x⁠y⁠z⁠ƿ⁠þ⁠ð⁠æ⁠/

You can enter the character using the HTML entity `&NoBreak;`, which seems to be to be the friendliest for both author and future editor. Entering the character directly and it will be unseen, to frustrate and to get deleted; entering the numerical entity is friendly for machines, but not humans who are not insufferable Unicode pedants.

> `/&NoBreak;slɑ:nti&nbsp;brækɪts&NoBreak;/`
>   /⁠slɑ:nti brækɪts⁠/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that it will have the desired effect as I can edit this post and double the length of your string (to see how it looks in the preview). The string of characters breaks at a `&NoBreak;` entity.

Comment: @andrewleach I only tested in Firefox and Chrome on Windows and FF on Android, so results may vary.

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Windows. https://imgur.com/hfLbb6e

Comment: @AndrewLeach I see now, but I don't think it's relevant. The no-break, like a non-breaking space, will "glue" its adjacent characters together, forcing any wrapping to occur at the next nearest space. It would be exceptionally rare to have text of such length required to both be wrapped in slashes *and* be printed on a single line, in which case you'd be forced to use <pre>.